# Как экранировать пробел в "ul.nav nav-pill"?

Tags: html, qt, webkit

Имеется такой тег: `<ul class="nav nav-pills">`.

Как экранировать пробел, чтобы этот тег был найден?

```
QWebElement el = element.findFirst("ul.nav nav-pills");
qDebug() << el.isNull();
```

Comment: Возможно, должно быть `"ul.nav.nav-pills"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про qt точно не скажу, но в CSS и JQuery это записывается так: `"ul.nav.nav-pills"`.

Думаю, должно сработать.